# How to send messages to other clients only in the sequence of adding clients?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

https://github.com/kakkarotssj/ChatApplication/blob/master/GroupChat/sever.py

https://github.com/kakkarotssj/ChatApplication/blob/master/GroupChat/client.py

When server starts, and suppose three clients got added. When first client try to send message, it will work and similarly client2 and client3 but problem occurs when this sequence breaks like suppose clients were added in the sequence of a, b and c and if b or c tries to send message to others, something weird happens.
My guess is target function of thread2, i.e handle_messages isn't functioning properly

Answer (score 0):

Change in approach of creating thread, resolves this issue.